# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd', using matplotlib via cgi on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, cgi

I have a simple webpage that is using a python script and cgi to display some data. I'm trying do import matplotlib when i get the following error:

```
 C:\wampstack-5.6.24-0\apache2\cgi-bin\makeImage.py in ()
     10 
     11 #For plotting
=>   12 import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
     13 
     14 #Setting the image size
matplotlib undefined, pyplot undefined
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in ()
   1180 
   1181 # this is the instance used by the matplotlib classes
=> 1182 rcParams = rc_params()
   1183 
   1184 if rcParams['examples.directory']:
rcParams undefined, rc_params = <function rc_params>
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in rc_params(fail_on_error=False)
   1013     default matplotlib rc file.
   1014     """
=> 1015     fname = matplotlib_fname()
   1016     if not os.path.exists(fname):
   1017         # this should never happen, default in mpl-data should always be found
fname undefined, global matplotlib_fname = <function matplotlib_fname>
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in matplotlib_fname()
    823                 return fname
    824 
=>  825     configdir = _get_configdir()
    826     if configdir is not None:
    827         fname = os.path.join(configdir, 'matplotlibrc')
configdir undefined, global _get_configdir = <function _get_configdir>
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in _get_configdir()
    678     5. A writable directory could not be found or created; return None.
    679     """
=>  680     return _get_config_or_cache_dir(_get_xdg_config_dir())
    681 
    682 get_configdir = verbose.wrap('CONFIGDIR=%s', _get_configdir, always=False)
global _get_config_or_cache_dir = <function _get_config_or_cache_dir>, global _get_xdg_config_dir = <function _get_xdg_config_dir>
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in _get_config_or_cache_dir(xdg_base=None)
    655                 return p
    656 
=>  657     return _create_tmp_config_dir()
    658 
    659 
global _create_tmp_config_dir = <function _create_tmp_config_dir>
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in _create_tmp_config_dir()
    581         return None
    582     try:
=>  583         username = getpass.getuser()
    584     except KeyError:
    585         username = str(os.getuid())
username undefined, getpass = <module 'getpass' from 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib\\getpass.py'>, getpass.getuser = <function getuser>
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\getpass.py in getuser()
    166 
    167     # If this fails, the exception will "explain" why
=>  168     import pwd
    169     return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
    170 
pwd undefined
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd' 
      args = ("No module named 'pwd'",) 
      msg = "No module named 'pwd'" 
      name = 'pwd' 
      path = None 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of ModuleNotFoundError object>
```

When i google pwd it says it's a linux thing, so whats going on?

Comment: Did you install pwd module?
If you on windws you should use winpwd

Comment: Pip cannot find any module called pwd or winpwd

Comment: What python version are you using? `getpass.getuser()` is supposed to work on Windows.

Comment: I think your Python is broken? This is supposed to work. How did you install Python? See e.g. https://github.com/conda-forge/matplotlib-feedstock/issues/114

Comment: I run python 3.6.1 downloaded from python.org while all required modules are installed via pip. I'm quite a noob at this so i wont be surprised if that's not how it's supposed to be done

Comment: I downloaded python 3.6.1 64-bit instead and reinstalled all my modules. No difference

Comment: I tried installing anaconda instead but i get the same errors